# Android install DBFlow library with gradle

Tags: android, dbflow

in my project i want to use DBFlow library as database ORM, after adding library in Gradle and sync i get this error:

```
Error:Could not find com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:4.0.0-beta7.
Required by:
    MyApp:app:unspecified
    Search in build.gradle files
```

i'm installing this library by the library documentation

```
def dbflow_version = "4.0.0-beta7"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${support_library}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_library}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${support_library}"

    annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-sqlcipher:${dbflow_version}"
    // RXJava 2 support
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-rx2:${dbflow_version}"
    ...
}
```

i clean and rebuild project and sync again, but this problem don't resolve

Answer (score 1):

Did you added this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
}}
```

in another gradle file?